# Oracle database link to a package saying table not found

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5, sql-grant

We've created a database link from an Oracle 12.1 DB to Oracle APEX 21.2 (Oracle 19c) and have granted EXECUTE to a package and granted SELECT to all the listed tables inside the function that's used by the function called in the package.

But when running calling the package function, it says table or view not found and gives the line number. However, if I execute that mentioned line from the database link, it works fine.

I tried granting SELECT to all the tables and EXECUTE to all the packages getting called from the initial package.

Comment: "link from an Oracle 12.1 DB to Oracle APEX 21.1". No: APEX is not a database. APEX is an application development framework that runs *in* an Oracle DB. Database links are between *databases*. What version of the Oracle DB is the remote database? Whatever account is running the package on the remote DB must have all of the correct privileges granted, and most likely they should be granted directly and not through roles.

Comment: Please share the erroring code

Comment: Are the grants made to a user or one of the user's roles? This might be a definer's rights versus owner's rights issue, in which case you may need to change the package to `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`.

Comment: @pmdba the apex db is using Oracle 19c. Grants are done directly to the user and not through roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables getting called from inside the package don't include the internal schema name, so you have to create a synonym for each table that is being called in the package.

```sql
create synonm table_name for schema_name.table_name
```

Because the second schema is executing a package from the source schema, it runs the code as is but when it tries to run select * from table x, it'll say not found because table x only exists in the source schema so we'll have to specify source_schema.x but since we can't control the code from the package from the second schema, one way to handle it is to create a synonym to translate

```sql
select * from x
```

to

```sql
select * from source_schema.x
```

Comment: I may be a touch out of my depth to constructively comment here as I don't have any  real experience with oracle or what exactly you're trying to achieve...

However, it might be helpful if you could elaborate a little on _why_ this was necessary. Creating a lot of aliases is generally, I would say, a bit of a code smell, so posterity (stack overflow answers are truly eternal) it might be best to be clear about the problem being solved so that poor lost souls are pointed the right way.